# IPTABLES: Route outgoing http requests to eth1

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

I am trying to route all outgoing HTTP requests LEAVING my server to go through a proxy (tinyproxy) on another server.  I want the transmission to the proxy to use our LAN which is on eth1.  No matter what I try, requests are going out on eth0.

I created this rule:

```
 iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT -o eth1 --to-destination 123.123.123.123:8888
```

However, that doesn't work.  The request is going out on eth0.  I know I am missing something big here, but I am out of ideas.  Any help would be appreciated.

Configuration:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:33:0E:
      inet addr:111.111.111.111  Bcast:111.111.111.255     Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::601:33ff:121:4f01/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1068434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:499051 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1087084291 (1.0 GiB)  TX bytes:104089629 (99.2 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:33:0E:
      inet addr:10.11.10.10  Bcast:10.11.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::601:33ff:121:4f02/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:10948267 (10.4 MiB)  TX bytes:633381 (618.5 KiB)

 route -n; cat /etc/network/interfaces
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
162.243.xx.xx   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.128.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         162.243..xx.xx   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory


iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5983 packets, 352K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 15734 packets, 1020K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4693 packets, 331K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            162.243..xx.xx
 3550  239K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.128.95.89
 7491  449K DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:10.128.3.132:8888
```

Comment: How are eth0 and eth1 configured?

Comment: Please do not obfuscate important information. What is the IP address of eth0? What is the IP address of the proxy server?

Comment: I did update the original question.

Comment: The IP Address of the proxy is 123.123.123.123, the IP of eth0 is 111.111.111.111.

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: For security reasons, I cannot give out the real IP's.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing table is in play here.

Your proxy is located on an Internet-routable IP address. Your `eth0` interface is configured with an Internet-routable IP address as well, likely with a default route pointed to your WAN gateway (Comcast, AT&T, etc.). Your `eth1` interface is configured with a non-Internet routable IP address. What's happening is your routing table is seeing the route to your destination address (the proxy server) through the `eth0` interface, thus the packet travels on that route.

I am willing to bet that your iptables rule isn't seeing any hits, and this explains why. What you are attempting to accomplish here in your current configuration **requires** the `eth0` interface.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for your input.  I have started to come to the same conclusion.  I just wish I could figure out how to route all outgoing requests from eth0 to proxyip:port on eth1.  I have been able to route all 80 requests to the proxy on eth0, but I am stuck right now on this problem.

Comment: If `eth1` had an internet-routable IP address like `eth0` then you would have no problem accomplishing your goal, since `eth1` would be able to route to the destination proxy server. Unfortunately, routing protocols prevail in this case. Good luck!

If you feel my answer addresses your issue, please mark it as such. :)

Comment: But the proxy it is to communicate with is on the same network as eth1?

Comment: If that's the case, then please post the output of the following commands: `route -n`, `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, and `iptables -t nat -vnL`. Please leave the output of those commands unmodified. Also, please post the **actual** IP address of your proxy server. If you don't want to post the full IP addresses of your interfaces or the proxy server, then feel free to exclude the last two octets (e.g. 12.34.x.x)

Comment: Updated the original post to include that data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem: According to your configuration, Both NIC are using Metric:1
If you want to use ETH1 as the primary NIC, **change the Metric to 0**.

Your Configuration:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:33:0E:
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  **Metric:1**

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:01:33:0E:
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  **Metric:1**

Comment: I don't want to use ETH1 as my primary NIC.

Comment: Then, change the Matric to 0 on ETH0. Remember, the lowest metric is the primary NIC.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I don't think you understand what exactly I am trying to do, but I do appreciate your effort. :)